# Selected button of a UITableViewCell get disappear when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm working on a project coded in swift 3 and I have a UIButton inside a UITableViewCell where the image changes once the button is tapped. Though the selected buttons get selected as intended, once the UITableview scrolls the selected images gets disappear since the cells are been reused. As I'm new to programming having troubles of writing the logic. Help would much appreciate the code as bellow.

CellFoRow

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        //Button_Action
         addSongButtonIdentifier(cell: cell, indexPath.row)

   }
```

This is where the cell is been created.

```
func addSongButtonIdentifier(cell: UITableViewCell, _ index: Int) {
    let addButton = cell.viewWithTag(TABLE_CELL_TAGS.addButton) as! UIButton

    //accessibilityIdentifier is used to identify a particular element which takes an input parameter of a string

    //assigning the indexpath button
    addButton.accessibilityIdentifier = String (index)
   // print("visible Index:",index)
    print("Index when scrolling :",addButton.accessibilityIdentifier!)


           addButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "correct"), for: UIControlState.selected)


           addButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "add_btn"), for: UIControlState.normal)


    addButton.isSelected = false
    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddToPlaylistViewController.tapFunction), for:.touchUpInside)


}
```

the tap function

```
func tapFunction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("IndexOfRow :",sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)
    // if let seporated by a comma defines, if let inside a if let. So if the first fails it wont come to second if let


    if let rowIndexString =  sender.accessibilityIdentifier, let rowIndex = Int(rowIndexString) {
    self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex] = !self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex]//toggle the state when tapped multiple times
    }
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected //image toggle
    print(" Array Data: ", self.sateOfNewSongArray)

    selectedSongList.removeAll()

    for (index, element) in self.sateOfNewSongArray.enumerated() {
        if element{
            print("true:", index)

            selectedSongList.append(songDetailsArray[index])

            print("selectedSongList :",selectedSongList)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: once tableview reload your selection would be gone because you need to store selected state in your data set instead of button state

Comment: You need to store the index or row number of the selected item.

Comment: I know the reason but having troubles of writting the logic, a code snippet would much appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain the button selection status at the controller level. You need to make changes to the model that you are using to configure your tableview.

I have created a similar scenario. I have used an array `selectionStatusArray` to maintain the button's selection status.

**Example:**

**1. `UIViewController` containing `UITableView`**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var selectionStatusArray = [false, false, false, false, false] //Array that maintains the button selection status

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return selectionStatusArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        addSongButtonIdentifier(cell: cell, indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }

    func addSongButtonIdentifier(cell: TableViewCell, _ index: Int)
    {
        cell.addButton.tag = index
        cell.addButton.isSelected = selectionStatusArray[index]
        cell.tapHandler = {
            self.selectionStatusArray[$0] = cell.addButton.isSelected
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Custom `UITableViewCell`**

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    var tapHandler: ((Int)->())?

    @IBAction func tapFunction(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        tapHandler?(sender.tag)
    }
}
```

You can configure the `UITableViewCell` according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You have this code `addButton.isSelected = false` which is causing the problem because I believe you are calling the function `addSongButtonIdentifier` inside `tableView delegate` method, you should not set all those property inside `tableView delegate`.

Instead you should do it initially and only once for each of your cell like either in storyboard itself or by providing a model to cell class.

Comment: Your code is correct but the way you are using it is a bit wrong, so I can suggest you a correct approach if you show me how are you calling the function addSongButtonIdentifier.