# UITableViewCell images disappear when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a UIButton inside a UITableViewCell where the image changes once the button is tapped. Though the selected buttons get selected as intended, once the UITableView scrolls, the selected images disappear since the cells are reused.

I'm having trouble writing the logic. Please help.

My code is below, in Swift 3.

CellForRow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    //Button_Action
    addSongButtonIdentifier(cell: cell, indexPath.row)
}
```

This is where the cell is created:

```
func addSongButtonIdentifier(cell: UITableViewCell, _ index: Int) {
    let addButton = cell.viewWithTag(TABLE_CELL_TAGS.addButton) as! UIButton

    //accessibilityIdentifier is used to identify a particular element which takes an input parameter of a string

    //assigning the indexpath button
    addButton.accessibilityIdentifier = String (index)
    // print("visible Index:",index)
    print("Index when scrolling :",addButton.accessibilityIdentifier!)

    addButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "correct"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    addButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "add_btn"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    addButton.isSelected = false
    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddToPlaylistViewController.tapFunction), for:.touchUpInside)
}
```

The tap function:

```
func tapFunction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("IndexOfRow :",sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)
    // if let seporated by a comma defines, if let inside a if let. So if the first fails it wont come to second if let


    if let rowIndexString =  sender.accessibilityIdentifier, let rowIndex = Int(rowIndexString) {
    self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex] = !self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex]//toggle the state when tapped multiple times
    }
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected //image toggle
    print(" Array Data: ", self.sateOfNewSongArray)

    selectedSongList.removeAll()

    for (index, element) in self.sateOfNewSongArray.enumerated() {
        if element{
            print("true:", index)

            selectedSongList.append(songDetailsArray[index])

            print("selectedSongList :",selectedSongList)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't ask same question multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627323/selected-button-of-a-uitableviewcell-get-disappear-when-scrolling/45629235#45629235

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selected button of a UITableViewCell get disappear when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627323/selected-button-of-a-uitableviewcell-get-disappear-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is logical error in `func addSongButtonIdentifier(cell: UITableViewCell, _ index: Int)` function at line `addButton.isSelected = false`

it should be `addButton.isSelected = self.sateOfNewSongArray[index]`

Since, cellForRowAtIndexpath method is called every time table is scrolled, it's resetting selected state of 'addButton'

Answer (score 1):

You need to have array where you store which indexes are selected like selectedSongList array that you have. Then in your cellForRow method you need to use bool proparty from this array to give selected or deselected state to your button or in your addSongButtonIdentifier method selected state need to be

```
addButton.isSelected = selectedSongList.contains(indexPath.row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Model class for filling UITableView and take UIImage varaivals in that model, which will hold the current image for cell. On click on button action just change the UIImage variable with current image.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach will be using a model class and keeping the track of each indiviual element in cell. But let me give you a quick fix.

Create a custom class of Button any where like this.

`class classname: UIButton {
       var imageName: String?
 }`

Go in your storyboard change the class from UIButton to classname

In your tableViewCellForIndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
     let addButton = cell.viewWithTag(TABLE_CELL_TAGS.addButton) as! classname

     if let imgName = addButton.imageName {
      addButton.setImage(UIImage(named: imgName), for: UIControlState.normal)
     } else {
       addButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "add_btn"), for:UIControlState.normal)
     } 
     addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddToPlaylistViewController.tapFunction), for:.touchUpInside)
 return cell
 }
```

Now let's move to your tapbutton implementation

func tapFunction(sender: classname) {

```
print("IndexOfRow :",sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)
// if let seporated by a comma defines, if let inside a if let. So if the first fails it wont come to second if let


if let rowIndexString =  sender.accessibilityIdentifier, let rowIndex = Int(rowIndexString) {
self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex] = !self.sateOfNewSongArray[rowIndex]//toggle the state when tapped multiple times
}
sender.imageName = sender.imageName == "correct" ? "add_btn" : "correct" //image toggle
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: sender.imageName), for:UIControlState.normal)

print(" Array Data: ", self.sateOfNewSongArray)

selectedSongList.removeAll()

for (index, element) in self.sateOfNewSongArray.enumerated() {
    if element{
        print("true:", index)

        selectedSongList.append(songDetailsArray[index])

        print("selectedSongList :",selectedSongList)
    }
}


}
```